# solving for eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Right now I am working on my thesis, which contains a part about wave propagation in periodic structures. Whilst I'm checking Bloch theory for solving this problem, I wondered how it would work with a 'normal' non-periodic structure. This has led me to an eigenvalue problem for the bloch wavenumber (or propagation constant), with its eigenvectors being the solution for the constants in the general solution of the 1D Euler-Bernoulli. (see [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew00B.png) for the system of equations defining the eigenvectors)

Now what puzzles me a bit, as I have never encountered it and cannot find any proper information, is that, first of all, the eigenvectors are all decoupled. Alas, that may be, thus if I substitute the first eigenvalue (see [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrnVQ.png)) the first equation becomes zero.

Now for my question, is it correct when I say that psi1 = C (arbitrary constant which will be defined by any boundary conditions) and: psi2 = psi3 = psi4 = 0? As this makes perfectly sense and doing this for all eigenvalues leads to the general solution again.

If so, what is the mathematical background that I may say so? As the only way I see it was by intuition and common sense, however having it mathematically explained will give me some clarity as well.

Cheers, and thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Having the PDE governing vibrations of an Euler-Bernoulli beam as follows:

$$
 m\ddot{w}(x,t) + EIw''''(x,t) = 0
$$

With the general solution in the spatial domain as:

$$
w(x) = A_{i}\mathrm{e}^{-ikx}+B_{i}\mathrm{e}^{ikx}+C_{i}\mathrm{e}^{-kx}+D_{i}\mathrm{e}^{kx}
$$

Now, if we'd have an infinite amount of these beams stacked along each other, think of a rail on periodic sleepers, the solutions of each cell (i.e. one beam on simple supports) are related via the following definition (Floquet, Bloch):
$$
w(x)_{i+1} = \mathrm{e}^{i \mu L}w(x)_{i}
$$

With this we can relate set-up B.C.'s governing the continuity of displacement, rotation, moment and shear force and solve for the propagation constants via an eigenvalue problem. Now, for a test, let us apply this on an infinite beam without simple supports. We have four B.C.'s as defined above, which give rise to the following system of equations for the constants:
$$
\textbf{H}\underline{A}_{i+1} = \textbf{K}\underline{A}_{i}
$$

Which may be rewritten with the use of $\underline{A}_{i+1} = \mathrm{e}^{i \mu L}\underline{A}_{i}$ as follows:
$$
\mathrm{e}^{i \mu L}\underline{A}_{i} = \textbf{H}^{-1}\textbf{K}\underline{A}_{i}
$$

And with $\textbf{T}=\textbf{H}^{-1}\textbf{K}$ the following eigenvalue problem arises:
$$
\left[\textbf{T}-\mathrm{e}^{i \mu L}\textbf{I}\right]\underline{A}_{i} = 0
$$

The matrix of which the eigenvalues must be determined is now as follows:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} k L}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \mu L} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} k L}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \mu L} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{k L}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \mu L} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{-k L}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \mu L}
\end{array}\right]
$$

For non-trivial solutions, singular matrix, thus determinant=0, which gives:
$$
\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} k L}-\mathrm{e}^{i \mu L}\right)\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} k L}-\mathrm{e}^{i \mu L}\right)\left(\mathrm{e}^{k L}-\mathrm{e}^{i \mu L}\right)\left(\mathrm{e}^{-k L}-\mathrm{e}^{i \mu L}\right)=0
$$

Which gives the following eigenvalues:
$$
\mu = -k, k, -ik, ik
$$

Substituting one of the eigenvalues, say $\mu = -k$, gives the following system to solve the eigenvectors:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} k L}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} k L} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{k L}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} k L} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{-k L}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} k L}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} \psi_{1} \\ \psi_{2} \\ \psi_{3} \\ \psi_{4} \end{array}\right]=0
$$

From here on, I think the question should clear. However, as writing this, I realised that to solve the values of $\mu$, the determinant is not even needed as the system itself is already uncoupled. Still, the question remains then whether it is true that all values of one eigenvector is zero except for one: i.e. $\psi_{1}$ in my example.

I hope this clarifies my question. If not, please let me know.

Comment: I see no equations at all, just expressions. What are the variables ? What is $I$ ??

Comment: This question is very unclear. Can you please add more details? Where do the equations come from? They look like they have to do with a partial differential equation.... can we see it? What mapping are the eigenvalues/vectors from?

Comment: I have edited the question on the matter.